# How to use pg_trgm operators(e.g. %>) in django framework?

Tags: python, django, string-formatting, string-substitution, pg-trgm

I'm using the `pg_trgm` for similarity search on PostgreSQL DB and I need to return the results to the front by using the Django model. But, I got a problem that the operator `%>` cannot be recognized by the Django framework.

Any advice?

Thank you.

I using the `model.objects.raw()` to execute SQL. I got an error response:

```
unsupported format character '>' (0x3e) at index 52
searchParam ='test'
mymodel.objects.raw('select * from mytable where columnname %> %s', [searchParam])
ValueError: response:unsupported format character '>' (0x3e) at index 52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is actually related to Python's string substitution.  To construct the final query string, Django does something like:

```
self.sql % self.params
```

This uses the old style %-formatting, which wants to interpret your `%>` as a string substitution mechanism, similar to `%s`, but that's not a valid combination.  To create a `%` character in the formatted string, you just have to use `%%` in your input string, like so:

```
In [1]: MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel WHERE myfield %%> %s', ['test'])
Out[1]: <RawQuerySet: SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel WHERE myfield %> test>
```

...

By the way, Django has [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity) on basic usage of `pg_trgm` without having to resort to raw query strings.  Just make sure you have a migration that activates the extension first:

> In addition to the `trigram_similar` lookup, you can use a couple of other expressions.
>
> To use them, you need to activate the `pg_trgm` [extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) on PostgreSQL.
>   You can install it using the `TrigramExtension` [migration operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations).

Comment: thank you give so many good advises and I resolved the problem by using the [%%>].

Comment: I used the trigramSimilarity.It is so great! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `%>` term with the escaped `%%` symbol. This should result in the following simple SQL query:

```
'select * from mytable where columnname = %%%s%%'
```

I believe this query should suffice for your purposes.

Comment: thank you.but the [=] does not meet similarity search which i shown above.

Comment: Mixed up. Try the answer now that uses escaped `%%` symbol.